# Telnyx primary webhook not receiving SMS

Tags: php, laravel, sms, webhooks

I have followed all the steps mentoined  [here](https://support.telnyx.com/en/articles/4348981-receiving-sms-on-your-telnyx-number#:%7E:text=Receiving%20SMS%20on%20Telnyx,the%20number%27s%20respective%20messaging%20profile.) : and although I can sent a post request to my webhook url somehow Telnyx is unable to send the message payload here whenever I receive a message.

here is my code

```
 public function receive_incoming_sms(Request $request){

            return  response()->json('Successfully Received',200);

}
```

here is the route defined in api.php

```
Route::post('/receive_incoming_sms', 'App\Http\Controllers\BucketController@receive_incoming_sms')->name('receive_incoming_sms');
```

but somehow telnyx is dropping the payload on the failover url which i created on https://webhook.site.

Comment: _"here is my code"_ - and you somehow implemented that on https://webhook.site/, is that what you are saying?

Comment: no,this code is on my main site . I am saying that even though  my route and code seems correct , I am still not receiving the payload on this . Instead the payload is going to the webhook site which I used as a failover URL .

Comment: Webhooks often get automatically disabled by the sender, if your endpoint failed to respond with a success status code in an appropriate amount of time, repeatedly. In that case, you probably need to re-activate it somewhere in the service's dashboard or something.

Comment: You should also check your access and error logs, to see if your server received any of these requests, and if so, how it responded or whether there's any related errors maybe.